# IIS locking files on Build but not on Rebuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

IIS likes to lock my project's DLL files. This prevents me from being able to Build. However, I can Rebuild All just fine (which aggravates me, because it takes a while). That on its own I could live with, if it didn't also prevent me from web publishing unless I first shut down IISExpress. I have tried the usual things, like checking whether there is something running in the background - I had Rebus for a while for testing purposes, but I removed it completely so it shouldn't be that - other people working on same SDK base (we use an internal SDK built on top of MVC stack and NHibernate) have their projects just fine, but on every computer, this project gets its DLL files locked.

My mind is stuck and I have no idea what to try. I've googled my eyes out, but nothing I've managed to find has been of use.

Ideas are welcome!